# Robotframework - regex working in python not matching

Tags: regex, robotframework

I have the following string:

```
https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123345&id=12334&__xts__%5B0%5D=12.AboYsxZUMIF4f8fZJLZ0LVrJZJ1jxGxzsmM2lJZJ8JoGFxO1UgViHWKvUSGwxVjkzwOjfCxL-FxJY9pfgvYP6L8Kwdd4tHZl-V1OaVvl40agK3dimgois_14R0sr9rSelJ5rt0WTU5fRoHNeGv2TR3sxrewYBf2wzfMQwDKV4pV4WbLkbqFd0f1mbcpx7VjMduLhbj2MXRHO_ERg1ssEesWbCHAzvZNSmXP6LycMlYHhbaoi6m7gTpBswQR-VBkdfjk3289dfsfsdfoIgfSxaxr9oa6FATiaF2V54-QWQOKgYtuO87YzKFnNh-m_mGgVkCYIA7-YwEK10zZCmSxEtSrmWSl5ZzSXNRpMg&__tn__=%2As%2As
```

I need to extract with a regex this part:

```
https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123345&id=12334
```

So I created this Regex (works perfectly in Python)

```
https?://(www\.|m\.)(facebook\.com)\/story\.php\?story_fbid=[0-9]+&id=[0-9]+
```

I've tryed to include in a robotfrawework script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String

*** Variables ***
${pattern}  SEPARATOR=
...  https?                          
...  ://                            
...  (www\\.|m\\.)                   
...  (facebook\\.com)                
...  /story\\.php\\?story_fbid=                         
...  [0-9]+                     
...  &id=
...  [0-9]+


*** Test Cases ***
String should match pattern
    ${url}=     Set Variable    https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123345&id=12334&__xts__%5B0%5D=12.AboYsxZUMIF4f8fZJLZ0LVrJZJ1jxGxzsmM2lJZJ8JoGFxO1UgViHWKvUSGwxVjkzwOjfCxL-FxJY9pfgvYP6L8Kwdd4tHZl-V1OaVvl40agK3dimgois_14R0sr9rSelJ5rt0WTU5fRoHNeGv2TR3sxrewYBf2wzfMQwDKV4pV4WbLkbqFd0f1mbcpx7VjMduLhbj2MXRHO_ERg1ssEesWbCHAzvZNSmXP6LycMlYHhbaoi6m7gTpBswQR-VBkdfjk3289dfsfsdfoIgfSxaxr9oa6FATiaF2V54-QWQOKgYtuO87YzKFnNh-m_mGgVkCYIA7-YwEK10zZCmSxEtSrmWSl5ZzSXNRpMg&__tn__=%2As%2As
    ${matchesp}=  Get lines matching regexp  ${url}  ${pattern} 
    run keyword if  $matchesp   Log To Console  OK MATCHED!
```

But it simply don't work at all (not giving any match).
I unable to understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get Regexp Matches` keyword instead of `Get Lines Matching Regexp`.

`Get Lines Matching Regexp` is used to find the specific line in a multiline string.

Code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           String

*** Variables ***
${pattern}        SEPARATOR=
...               https?
...               ://
...               (www\\.|m\\.)
...               (facebook\\.com)
...               /story\\.php\\?story_fbid=
...               [0-9]+
...               &id=
...               [0-9]+

*** Test Cases ***
String should match pattern
    ${url}=    Set Variable    https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123345&id=12334&__xts__%5B0%5D=12.AboYsxZUMIF4f8fZJLZ0LVrJZJ1jxGxzsmM2lJZJ8JoGFxO1UgViHWKvUSGwxVjkzwOjfCxL-FxJY9pfgvYP6L8Kwdd4tHZl-V1OaVvl40agK3dimgois_14R0sr9rSelJ5rt0WTU5fRoHNeGv2TR3sxrewYBf2wzfMQwDKV4pV4WbLkbqFd0f1mbcpx7VjMduLhbj2MXRHO_ERg1ssEesWbCHAzvZNSmXP6LycMlYHhbaoi6m7gTpBswQR-VBkdfjk3289dfsfsdfoIgfSxaxr9oa6FATiaF2V54-QWQOKgYtuO87YzKFnNh-m_mGgVkCYIA7-YwEK10zZCmSxEtSrmWSl5ZzSXNRpMg&__tn__=%2As%2As
    ${matchesp}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${url}    ${pattern}
    Log To Console    \n${matchesp}
```

Output:

```
==============================================================================
String should match pattern                                           ..
['https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=123345&id=12334']
String should match pattern                                           | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Main                                                                  | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```